# How to represent C++ private inheritance in an UML diagram?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, uml, class-diagram

In C++, one can create a sub-class via `public`, `protected`, or `private` inheritance. What's the notation to indicate that in a UML class diagram? I'm thinking about putting a label on the arrow but not sure if that's common practice.

Comment: Terminology note: What we call access levels (`public`, `protected`, and `private`) in C++, UML calls "visibility". That said, there will probably be notation for restricted visibility in Inheritance but I don't know it and have never used it.

Comment: private inheritance is basically composition

Comment: I thought about that as well but I'm afraid that using a composition arrow (solid diamond from the derived class) would confuse people more since it's still coded like inheritance in C++ terminology.

Comment: Inheritance is not composition. Both are different concepts. I have no idea what a "private inheritance" would mean.

Comment: the fact the inheritance can be public/protected/private to 'change' the visibility of the inherited members is specific to C++, there is nothing comparable in UML

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 a generalization is not a property (composition or not) and a property (composition or not) is not a generalization, the closer common ancestor is Element being the root class of all in UML. Why are you saying *private inheritance is basically composition* ?

Comment: In a top-down methodology, you first create a UML class diagram without thinking about the C++ representation. Suppose you have a composition in that diagram. Then you want to implement it using C++. You may decide to implement the composition using private inheritance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What is private inheritance in C++?

[Private inheritance](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance) in C++, such as:

```
class B1 {
public: 
   void test(); 
   ...
};
class D1 : private B1 {
public:
   void demo() { test(); }
...
};
```

means that every instance of `D1` is an instance of `B1`, but that is hidden for the outside world.  This strange construct aims at implementing the derived class by reusing the code of the base class, but as if there would be no inheritance.

In consequence, unlike public inheritance, a D1 object could not be used where a B1 object is expected:

```
 B1 *p = new D1;     //ouch -> error: ‘B1’ is an inaccessible base of ‘D1’
```

### Is this UML inheritance?

In UML, when a derived class specializes a more general base classe, it means the following:

> Type conformance means that if one Type conforms to another, then any instance of the first Type may be used as the value of a TypedElement whose type is declared to be the second Type. A Classifier is a Type, and **conforms** to itself and **to all of its generalizations**.

So in UML, if D1 specialises (i.e. inherits from) B1, a D1 instance could always be be used in place of a B1 object.  This does not match the C++ private inheritance.

Moreover, there is not either a realization relationship between an interface and its implementations either, since D1 does not conform to the interface defined by B1:

> An InterfaceRealization relationship between a BehavioredClassifier and an Interface implies that the BehavioredClassifier conforms to the contract specified by the Interface by supporting the set of Features owned by the Interface, and any of its parent Interfaces.

### How to represent it in standard UML?

Obviously, there is a dependency:  D1 depends on B1.  So you could simply show a dependency.  But this does not really help to grasp the kind of relationship and is not very useful. (unless you add a comment to explain)

A better approach would therefore be to map UML to match the C++ semantics.  In this regard, you could envisage to model the private inheritance as a composition relation:

[image]

[Why?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm)  Because the situation is very similar (although not completely) to the following composition alternative:

```
class B2 {
public: 
   void test(); 
   ...
};

class D2 {
private: 
   B2 base;  // instead of private inheritance
public:
   void demo() { base.test(); }  // base members accessed via base
...
};
```

So all we do in the UML model here, is to make explicit that in any D1 instance, there is a B1 sub-object not accessible directly from the outside world.

### Edit: Other alternatives?

In the former and now [obsolete UML 1.4](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/1.4/), a generalization relationship could have a stereotype `«Implementation»` that would have fulfilled your need, but is no longer supported since 2005, and might mislead some readers who associate "implementation" with interface:

> Specifies that the child inherits the implementation of the parent (its attributes, operations and methods) but does not make public the supplier's interface, nor guarantee to suport them, thereby violating substituability.  This is private inheritance and is usually used only for programming implementation puproposes.

Digging a little bit in the UML metamodel,  it appears that generalization has a `isSubstitutable` property which is true by default.  So you could think of using your own language-specific **[profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile_(UML))**, and define therein a stereotypes `«Private inheritance»` and `«Protected inheritance»` for a specialization of the `Generalization` metamodel element, both with `isSubstituable=false`.  This would allow:

[image]

This could be a very pragmatic and readable way to convey your language-specific design intent, including that a D1 object is not substituable for B1.  But be aware that this is not without risks:  `isSubsituable` is only about run time promises, and has in reality no impact regarding inheritance rules of public features in UML. Automated tools might therefore come to a different conclusion than your readers (this is why I proposed another approach above).

Comment: Hello, long time ;-) The composition does not *represent* in UML the C++ private inheritance, in the best case it partially *simulates* it, it does from the  outside world but not at all from the inheriting class in C++.

Comment: @bruno Hello :-)! yes, a fair point: it’s indeed not about representing it, but representing something equivalent, to communicate the spirit of the design. For the inheriting class, it’s not exactly the same: that’s what I meant with “although not completely”: because for example you’d need to prefix inherited members with base, you have to forward an inherited member call instead of just exposing the name, etc...). It’s not perfect, but it’s the closest I could find (and as Sutter’s linked blog post suggests, there are not so many uses for private inheritance).

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 implementation details ? what is implementation detail and what is not for you ? In C++ D2 inherits B2 and D2 knows that, but in UML using a composition D2 does not inherits B2 and D2 know that, for me  this is not an implementation details ;)

Comment: yes this is why I prefer to speak about *simulation* rather than *representation* which supposes equivalence which we don't have here

Comment: @bruno digging a little bit in former versions of UML and UML metamodel,  I've added some (less recommended) alternatives.  I warn about risks regarding tools, and since in BOUML you have some code generation,  could you confirm my warning, or do I see more risks than there are in reality?

Comment: Yes to use *isSubsituable* to change the code generation is not the right way, the main reason is that means (as you said) the code generator interprets *isSubsituable* in a way different than UML and then the readers, a second reason is then you 'lost' that attribute and cannot use it for what it is, and third even supposing that means private inheritance in the generated code you need something else in case you want to generate protected inheritance. ...

Comment: ... So better to extend UML rather than modify an existing definition of it, and then to add stereotypes as you proposed, but *without* requiring *isSubsituable=false*

Comment: After the goal being to generate C++ private (protected) inheritance that means the used tool manages / knows the added stereotype(s). In BoUML I do not use a stereotype for that but when you edit the generalization you can specify the visibility to use in C++ with an added attribute not part of UML; That means the specificity of the C++ inheritance is not visible in a class diagram, but a the user wanting to show that is free to use a stereotype from him (part or not of a profile, BoUML is 'pragmatic' and not strict to simplify users life)

Answer (score 0):

I would say with UML it's usually the type of relationship it has for example one to one or one to many. If you are deriving from an abstract class, interface or just another base class. Usually during inheritance you would use the protected keyword so that everything is private to any class outside of inheritance.
After inheriting from a base class you can also override methods from the base class as well as run the base method from inside the overridden method.

I believe what you are looking for here is the protected keyword which basically is private inheritance. Only related classes have the ability to access such members. For example, you create a base class with protected members and then use these members in inherited classes or classes that derive from the base.
Here is more info
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm

Comment: Maybe I missed the point, but how exactly do you recommend to represent private (or protected of you prefer) inheritance in UML, considering that UML specialization is implicitly based on public inheritance?