How To Show on a UML Class Diagram that a Class contains another class
Here is class Foo, that contains a struct Bar
#include <iostream>
class Foo{
    private:
        struct Bar{
               static int x, y;
        };
    public:
        void printBar(){
            std::cout<<Bar::x<<", "<<Bar::y<<"\n";
        }
};

I would be most grateful if someone could inform me, how I would represent such a relationship between these two classes in a UML class diagram?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77067405/uml-class-diagram-with-struct-defined-inside-class

Yes it does. Thanks!

This might help too : https://www.uml-diagrams.org/nested-classifier.html. The actual notation you can use may depend on the UML tooling you are using.. so maybe you can say something about that too

That is indeed helpful, thanks.
